# How do I split a mesh of quads into their true triangles?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am trying to make a low-poly triangulated version of the built-in torus.

1. I insert a torus.
2. Decimate the torus (un-subdivide, 3 iters)
3. I now have a torus made out of quads.

A problem arises when I add a triangulate modifier: the torus becomes very "skinny". That's because it splits the quads into two triangles, and you get "indents" due to the shape. In order to really understand this, try it for yourself, rotate the camera a bit while the triangulate modifier is on and while it's off. You'll get what I mean.

edit: see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Mu7.jpg). The blue torus looks much nicer, right? That's the quad version. The red torus is the "skinny" triangulated one.
[image: bony torus]
edit2: setting the quad method to "fixed" seems like what I'm trying to do, but it makes [this weird artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhcRu.jpg), what's that about?
[image]

How do I split a quad into it's true 4 triangles? So that the geometry of the quad becomes the hidden geometry of the quad that blender renders?

edit3: I have since corrected the mesh generated by fixed triangulation, but I would still like to know for the future.

Comment: thanks, I added some images.

Comment: Triangulating a non-planar quad _will_ expose valleys/peaks.. they're already there, geometrically; the shading just conceals them .  Maybe Alt-P poking the quads will get you closer to what you want?

Comment: @RobinBetts yeah, it's a concave/not concave issue I think.